# How to show common and uncommon value from two table using CI framework

Tags: sql

I have Two table t1 and t2

in table t1

id----value

---

1 -----15

3 -----18

in table t2

id--------name

---   ----

1-------- x

2-------- y

3-------- z

4---------m

i want to show

id---- name---- value

--     ----    -----

1 ---- x ------ 15

2 ---- y -----  null

3 ---- z ----- 18

4 ---- m ----- null

table t2 has all record but t1 has some of t1 id.

How can I do?

Comment: Can you show us what queries you have tried and what results you got?

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('t2');
$this->db->join('t1', 't2.id = t1.id', 'left outer');
$query = $this->db->get();  
$result = $query->result(); show only id 1 and 3 and all name and value with null

Comment: @user, please add your query to the question; don't try to post code in a comment box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.value
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```